# MySQL dump from AWS

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am currently trying to take a dump of my database from Amazon Web Services RDS.  In my python script, I create the database instance from a snapshot of another instance then assign the newly created instance to a Security group I also create in the script.  In this seucrity group, I authorize my ip address.  I then us this command:

```
command = "mysqldump -h %s -u root -p%s %s > myfile.sql" \
      % (command_endpoint, password, name)

os.system(command)
```

where command is

```
"mysqldump -h backup-pivotalbase-db.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -pxxx backup-pivotalbase-db > myfile.sql
```

I get the error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'backup-pivotalbase-db' when selecting the database
```

I know that the database exists because I just created it.  Can some one tell me why my program cannot find the database?

Comment: The error is not about the name of the instance, it's about thr namr of the *schema* you are telling mysqldump to back up.

Comment: Yup I figured that out thanks.  Beginner at MySQL, in case you couldn’t tell.